# Fourier series for $a_k$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am stuck in the following problem: I have the following Fourier series:
$$\cos (\alpha x)= \frac{1}{2}a_0+ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k\cos(kx)$$
$-\pi\leq x \leq \pi$, and $\alpha>0$ and not an integer.
The question is to find explicit expressions for the Fourier coefficients $a_k$.
I started with the standard series:
$$a_k=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(\alpha x) \cdot \cos (kx) dx$$
Now I know that $\cos a \cos b= \frac{1}{2}\big[\cos(a-b)+\cos(a+b)\big]$
Plugging in this values to obtain:
$$a_k=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(\alpha -k)x +\cos(\alpha +k)x dx$$
Which can be changed to because I prefer to put in zero's:
$$a_k=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{o}^{\pi}\cos(\alpha -k)x +\cos(\alpha +k)x dx$$
Now I'll do the integration to obtain:
$$a_k=\frac{1}{\pi}\bigg[\frac{1}{\alpha -k}\sin(\alpha-k)x+\frac{1}{a+k}\sin(\alpha +k)x\bigg]_{0}^{\pi}$$
Putting in the values for ${\pi}$ and $0$ giving:
$$a_k=\frac{1}{\pi}\bigg[\frac{1}{a-k}\sin(a-k)\pi+\frac{1}{a+k}\sin(a+k)\pi\bigg]$$
Again using a trick:$sin(a+/-b)=\sin a\cos b +/-\cos a \sin b$ which result in:
$$a_k=\frac{1}{\pi}\bigg[\frac{1}{\alpha-k}\sin(\alpha \pi)\cos k\pi -\cos \alpha \pi \sin k\pi+\frac{1}{\alpha +k}\sin(\alpha \pi)\cos k\pi+ \cos \alpha \pi \sin k \pi)\bigg]$$
Knowing that: $\sin k\pi = 0$ and $\cos k \pi= (-1)^k$, to obtain:
$$a_k=\frac{1}{\pi}\bigg[\frac{1}{\alpha-k}\sin(\alpha \pi)(-1)^k +\frac{1}{\alpha +k}\sin(\alpha \pi)(-1)^k \bigg]$$
Which can be expressed:
$$a_k=\frac{1}{\pi} (-1)^k \sin \alpha \pi \bigg[\frac{1}{\alpha-k} +\frac{1}{\alpha +k} \bigg]$$
This can be rearranged to:$$a_k=\frac{1}{\pi} (-1)^{k-1} \sin \alpha \pi \bigg[\frac{2\alpha}{k^2 - \alpha^2} \bigg]$$

But this is totally not the answer of the book which says:

$$\cos \alpha x= \frac {\sin \alpha \pi}{\alpha \pi}+ \frac{2 \alpha}{\pi}\sin \alpha \pi \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{\cos kx}{k^2-\alpha^2}$$

Did I start wrong?

Comment: Minor math mistake: $\frac{1}{\alpha - k} +\frac{1}{\alpha + k} = \frac{\alpha+k+\alpha-k}{\alpha^2 - k^2} = \frac{2 \alpha}{\alpha^2 -k^2}$!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So by correcting the mistake:
$$a_k=\frac{2\alpha}{\pi} (-1)^{k-1} \sin \alpha \pi \bigg[\frac{1}{k^2 - \alpha^2} \bigg]$$
so:

$$\cos (\alpha x)=\frac{1}{2}a_0+\frac{2\alpha}{\pi}\sin\alpha \pi\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{\cos (kx)}{k^2-\alpha^2}$$

for $k=0$ we obtain:$\frac{\ sin\alpha \pi}{\alpha \pi}$

Hence the required relation:

$$\cos \alpha x= \frac {\sin \alpha \pi}{\alpha \pi}+ \frac{2 \alpha}{\pi}\sin \alpha \pi \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{\cos kx}{k^2-\alpha^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

You have only 2 mistakes
1. $\frac{1}{\alpha-k}+\frac{1}{\alpha+k}=\frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2-k^2}$
2. You did not show your work computing $a_0$ so it is unknown if you got that or not